# Comparator circuit analysis

Tags: circuit-analysis, comparator

comparators are used to measure whether a particular voltage is above or below reference voltage. It makes sense for the led to turn on when input voltage (v+ > v-) and turn off for input voltage ( v+ < v-) (please refer to the "Comparator circuit with solution" image)

My question is: what would happen to the led ( turn on/off) if we attach a negative feedback to the comparator circuit ?

if vin < 5v what happens to LED?
if vin > 5v what happens to LED?

I think since the pins are the same. The LED operation would be the opposite but I don't know why

[image: problem]

[image]

Comment: If the 5v source is "stiff" - such as a power supply or battery there will be no negative feedback.

Answer (score 1):

There is no negative feedback in your circuit, so the pins \$v_{-}=v_{+}\$ doesn't apply.

The reason why there is no negative feedback is because the opamp output *can't* influence the negative input pin. The negative input pin is fixed to 5V regardless of what the opamp does.

To have "true" negative feedback, you would have to remove the 5V voltage source, but in that case there would be no current through the LED (there is no path for the current to follow) and it would never turn on.

Answer (score 0):

This is what an open-collector comparator looks like inside:

[image]

and here is the relevant section from the [LM311 datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm211.pdf):

> 9.2.2.1 Input Voltage Range
>
> When choosing the input voltage range, consider the input common mode voltage range (V_ICR). Operation outside of this range can yield incorrect comparisons.
>
> The following list describes the outcomes of some input voltage situations.
>
> • When both IN– and IN+ are both within the common-mode range:
>
> – If IN– is higher than IN+ and the offset voltage, the output is low and the output transistor is sinking
> current
>
> – If IN– is lower than IN+ and the offset voltage, the output is high impedance and the output transistor is
> not conducting
>
> • When IN– is higher than common mode and IN+ is within common mode, the output is low and the output transistor is sinking current
>
> • When IN+ is higher than common mode and IN– is within common mode, the output is high impedance and the output transistor is not conducting
>
> • When IN– and IN+ are both higher than common mode, the output is undefined

Comment: in this question is IN- and IN+ within the common-mode range? how do I know?

Comment: For the purpose of answering your question you can assume the inputs are in the common-mode range.

Comment: this is what I think:

v+ < v- 
from your datasheet
IN+ < IN -
The output is low and LED will off
-but with feedback with negative:
"the output is high and LED will be on"


In v+ > v- 
from you datasheet
IN+ > IN - 
The output is high and LED will be on
-but with negative feedback:
"the output is low and LED will turn off"

Comment: What do you mean "but with feedback with negative"? When IN+ > IN- the output is not high, rather, the output transistor is off (not conducting).

Comment: Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Consider two circuits (with no comparators, just a resistor and LED), and consider the state of each circuit when the voltage at X is +5V or 0V:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTu9Kd.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Bearing in mind that current always flows from the higher potential to lower, it's pretty easy to see in which cases the LED will be lit, and in which cases it's not. If the anode side of the LED is on the same side as the higher potential, current can flow, and the LED is lit. Otherwise the LED is dark.

Your top circuit corresponds to the configuration on the right here, where the anode side of the resistor+LED pair is fixed at +5V. In this configuration, the LED is *on* when X is *low* at 0V.

Contrast that with the configuration on the left, which corresponds to the LED/resistor configuration of your second circuit. Here the LED is *on* only when X is *high*, at +5V.

By connecting X to a comparator output (assuming that this output is *not* open collector, which is a complication I will talk about below), and with all other things being equal, these two configurations have opposite behaviour.

However, you may also flip behaviour by swapping the inverting and non-inverting of the comparator. The following two circuits would behave identically, because we flipped behaviour once by exchanging the inverting and non-inverting inputs, and then flipped it back again by also changing the LED/resistor configuration from common anode to common cathode:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flCA9o.png)</sup>

An open collector comparator cannot drive an LED in the configuration of the second second circuit you showed us (problem #3), because its output can only *sink* current from a higher potential, say +5V. That second circuit *will not work* if the comparator is an open-collector output type, because such comparators can pull their outputs low, but cannot raise their output voltage without external assistance.

As far as your question about negative feedback is concerned, negative feedback causes systems to operate linearly, with continuously variable analogue voltages, as opposed to the very digital high/low behaviour you see in these circuits. Negative feedback would cause the LED to glow with varying brightness, which in both of your circuits (which are strictly digital) is *not* the case. In your two circuits the LED is completely on or completely off.

I think you are confused because your top circuit *looks* like it has negative feedback. It does *not*. The inverting input of that comparator/op-amp is fixed at +5V, and does not vary with the output. Negative feedback means that the inverting input varies somewhat in phase with variations in the output. That is, as the output rises in potential, so does the inverting input to some degree, and vice versa. In this case the inverting input does not vary because it is clamped to an unchanging +5V potential.